# Excessive page refreshing with JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, out-of-memory, page-refresh

I have the following code setup: (for a uni project).

Essentially, Books Store.php is meant to update and display a list of books every 5 minutes.

```
// Book Store.php
<head>
    <script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
</body>
    <div class = "container-fluid">
    <div id = "Books"></div>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Books();
        setInterval(Books, 300000);
        $.ajaxSetup({cache: true});
    });
    function Books() {
        $("#Books").load("php/Books.php");
    }
</script>
```

In turn,  Books.php is then meant to update and display a list of Book Pages  every 30 seconds.

```
// Books.php
// Get List of books from MySQL

// FOR EACH BOOK .....
<div id = "BookPages"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        BookPages();
        setInterval(BookPages, 30000);
        $.ajaxSetup({cache: true});
    });
    function BookPages() {
        $("#BookPages").load("php/BookPages.php");
    }
</script>
//  CLOSE FOR LOOP
```

One the first page load, everything works fine, until BooksStore.php tries to reload the books list. What happens is that Books.php will reload correctly, but the BooksPages.php will reload multiple times.

BookStore Reloads 2nd Time - Books.php will reload BooksPages.php 2 times.

BookStore Reloads 3nd Time - Books.php will reload BooksPages.php 6 times.

BookStore Reloads 4nd Time - Books.php will reload BooksPages.php 8 times.

BookStore Reloads 5nd Time - Books.php will reload BooksPages.php 12 times.

And so on until the server begins to slow down & run out of resources.... ???  Why is this happening / how to fix it.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: You are calling `setInterval(BookPages, 30000);` for each call to `php/Books.php`. You need to check if the interval for `BookPages` has been called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Zim says, try using **clearInterval()** an check if your code now works as expected:

**BookStore.php**

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="Books"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var int1;

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            if (int1)
                clearInterval(int1);

            Books();
            int1 = setInterval(Books, 300000);
            $.ajaxSetup({cache: true});
        });

        function Books()
        {
            $("#Books").load("php/Books.php");
        }    
    </script>
</body>
```

**Books.php**

```
<div id="BookPages"></div>

<script>
    var int2;

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        if (int2)
            clearInterval(int2);

        BookPages();
        int2 = setInterval(BookPages, 30000);
        $.ajaxSetup({cache: true});
    });

    function BookPages()
    {
        $("#BookPages").load("php/BookPages.php");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `Store.php` is initializing the call of Books() function every 5 minutes. So each time it creates a new schedule for `BookPages` unless you clear the previous one by using the function `clearInterval()`. So before calling the `Books()` function you should clear the schedule of `BookPages()`.

You can learn the usage of `clearInterval()` from this link: [clearInterval w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion,  I went with your solution but i used @D. Smania's code.